# Web-based Samba client interface for headless system

Tags: samba, browser, user-interface, headless

I run a file server on a Raspberry Pi at home. Also at home on another Raspberry PI; I'm running Openelec Kodi.

The instance that I'm envisioning is where my (not-very-tech-savvy) wife is at home wanting to watch a video clip that I have on my file server. I'm at work and want to copy it from the file-server to the Kodi for her.

The problem is that I need now to copy the file over the network to the other Pi running Kodi. Ideally I'd like to use the Samba to achieve this.

The file server is running a headless Jessie (Raspbian) install. I have a number of other things running on it: a web server, owncloud, transmission and a few other scripts.

What I'd like to have is a web interface to a commander-like (think Norton Commander / Total Commander / etc) interface that I could use to copy/move/delete files between a samba server and the local OS (preferably running on a non-commonly-used port).

**NEEDS**

- Browser Interface
- Copy/Move files from local OS to remote PC
- Must be user controlled (not a periodically run rsync)
- Interface must run on a non-standard port (I'm using 80 for something already)

**WANTS**

- I'd prefer it to use Samba, but ftp would also be OK
- Progress bars!

Does this exist?

Comment: kodi can directly index and serve videos from a samba server, isnt that the solution?

Comment: Why not  a remote session with SSH?

Comment: @meuh, Thanks, However, I'm looking for something that I can control via the web, instead of having ALL the content available all the time.

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero I do SSH in, but my limited experience with `smbclient` has proven pretty bad. So I'm looking for the solution I asked about above.

Comment: perhaps [webmin](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Modules) can do what you want? I'm not sure if you'ld want to run it on the kodi or the server. It has a standalone web service with pages to do uploads and a file manager gui.

Comment: @meuh Hah! Awesome! I actually was unaware of Webmin until I started adding tags to this question, I was trying to add `web-interface` (which doesn't exist) and it offered `webmin` instead. I've since been looking into it and I'm willing to give it a shot. (busy looking at RPi install guide right now at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=6096)

Comment: Try also [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp). Is _secure copy_ over SSH. I think is easy to use and easy to find examples (google-em ;D ). And if you need to transfer a lot of files pipe scp with gzip (for example).

Comment: @JoséM.Carnero Transfers don't need to be secure at all (yet?). My home network is pretty secure, not unbreakable, but I don't really have stuff there that anyone would want access to. Would I be able to initiate a copy from the Pi to the Kodi using scp from a different location? I've only ever used `winscp` and that was a very, very long time ago.

Comment: If the Pi have an SSH server you can login in remotely to the Pi and do then SCP from the Pi to the Kodi (or whatever you want).